# In a slideshow, how do I prevent slides from receiving "click" events after dragging?

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a slideshow:

```
        <div (mousedown)="onMouseDown($event)"
          (mousemove)="onMouseMove($event)"
          (mouseup)="onMouseUp($event)">
          <div class="swiper-wrapper">
            <div *ngFor="let item of items; index as i;">
              <custom-slide class="custom-slide"></custom-slide>
            </div>
          </div> 
        </div>
```

Methods `onMouseDown`, `onMouseMove` and `onMouseUp` are for dargging it using mouse.

The `custom-slide` Angular component listens to `click` events and pops up a dialog upon clicks.

But the problem is every time finish dragging the slideshow, a `click` event is always sent to a `custom-slide` component, therefore a dialog is popped up, which is what I want to avoid.

I tried to write the `onMouseUp` as below, but it doesn't work

```
  onMouseUp() {
    this.mouseIsDown = false;

    const elements = document.getElementsByClassName("custom-slide");

    if(this.isScrolling) {
      for(let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++){
        elements[i].addEventListener("click", this.preventClick);
      }
    } else {
      for(let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++){
        elements[i].removeEventListener("click", this.preventClick);
      }
    }

    this.isScrolling = false;
  }

  preventClick(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
  }
```

Although in the `preventClick` method I prevented everything, but the slide can still receive the `click` event and pop up the dialog...

Could anyone teach me how to prevent it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the following approach and it solved the problem:

in the slideshow component, which is where the `mouseUp` and `mouseMove` functions are located, keep a `boolean` variable indicating whether the user is dragging.

Then share this variable with the slide component via Emitter or some other ways.

I did it by placing both the variables and functions in a controller class, so I can share an instance of the class between the two components.

Then, in the slide component's `click` listener function, check if the variable is true, which means the user was dragging before releasing the left mouse button.

If yes, that means we want to ignore it, becase the user was dragging instead of  clicking, and the click listener should return directly and do nothing.

If no, that means the user clicked it deliberately, then the listener function should keep finishing its job.

Answer (score 0):

It depends...maybe You can catch event before custom-slide click event handler recives it if click event is on bubbling phase. then you can add your click-prevent listener on capturing phase which comes before bubbling phase

```
elements[i].addEventListener('click', this.preventClick, true);
```

specify third parameter as true (useCapture)